# fetch the jwt value from Set-Cookie header in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, k6

I am using javascript k6 load testing tool to make a http.post request to our application server.

The server sends me a response back and it also sends the response headers.

One of the response headers is the below Set-Cookie header sent back to me:
Set-Cookie : xx00000000xxxxxxxxxx0000000000xx-jwt=<jwt_token>; path=/; expires=Fri, 23 Apr 2021 04:15:19 GMT; domain=.somedomain.com; samesite=none; secure

For making subsequent requests through my k6 testing tool to my server - i would like to parse the Set-Cookie value above and fetch the jwt value only of <jwt_token> and store in a variable like => fetched_jwt=<jwt_token>

How can i fetch the value for jwt from the Set-Cookie headers that has multiple values sent back to me by the server?

Comment: so, you want to parse cookie so you can get the jwt token, is that correct? if so you can do it with [cookie library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie). it will parse the cookie into js object so you can pick the jwt

Comment: I just clarified few other details in my question. I took a look at the above cookie library but it seems it is used at the server side. I would like to parse the Set-Cookie at the client side.

Comment: why you would like to parse Set-cookie on client side? it is server side thing. you may want to parse cookie header instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MDN, [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) syntax is like this

```
Set-Cookie: <cookie-name>=<cookie-value>
// and also can be followed by other attribute
Set-Cookie: <cookie-name>=<cookie-value>; Domain=<domain-value>; Secure; HttpOnly
// but no matter what attributes behind it, cookie name and value will be on first
```

So, if you want parse it, just get the first attribute. You can do it with [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), and then get the first.

```js
const myCookie = unparsedCookie.split(';')[0];
```

And use `String.prototype.split()` again to get its name and value.

```js
const [name, value] = myCookie.split('=');
```

```js
const unparsedCookie = 'xx00000000xxxxxxxxxx0000000000xx-jwt=<jwt_token>; path=/; expires=Fri, 23 Apr 2021 04:15:19 GMT; domain=.somedomain.com; samesite=none; secure';

const myCookie = unparsedCookie.split(';')[0];
const [name, value] = myCookie.split('=');

console.log(name);
console.log(value);
```

But keep in mind that Set-cookie might be encoded as URI Component.

> A `<cookie-value>` can optionally be wrapped in double quotes and include any US-ASCII characters excluding control characters, Whitespace, double quotes, comma, semicolon, and backslash. Encoding: Many implementations perform URL encoding on cookie values, however it is not required per the RFC specification. It does help satisfying the requirements about which characters are allowed for  though.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie)

So, you might be needed to decode it with [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

But, since your case is JWT token, you don't have to worry about that. JWT should be generated as base64url which friendly to url.